# jQuery / CSS - Changing slider to go beyond 100% but stay inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently editing a jQuery slider. I want to have the same effect that the jQuery UI slider have - there you can input a max, like "2500", and then the slider can go to that, without breaking out of the div / screen.

Here is my slider: http://jsfiddle.net/uHNsv/

```
#slider {
  height: auto;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
#slider .ui-slider-handle {
  top: 65px !important;
}

#slider::before, .slider-filled-top {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(70deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(70deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(70deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(70deg);
  transform: rotateX(70deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -moz-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
  -o-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

#slider {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  -webkit-perspective: 200;
  -moz-perspective: 200;
  -ms-perspective: 200;
  -o-perspective: 200;
  perspective: 200;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#slider input[type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
}
#slider input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-apperance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -ms-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: dimgrey 0 2px 2px -1px;
  -moz-box-shadow: dimgrey 0 2px 2px -1px;
  box-shadow: dimgrey 0 2px 2px -1px;
}
#slider::before, #slider::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.6);
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
#slider::before {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
#slider::after {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9)), color-stop(100%, rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.9)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.9) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.9) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.9) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.9) 0%, rgba(228, 228, 228, 0.9) 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 10px 10px -5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 10px 10px -5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 10px 10px -5px;
}

.slider-filled-top,
.slider-filled-front {
  background: #9cde45;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.slider-filled-front {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, #4aaf1b), color-stop(100%, #82d02f));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4aaf1b 0%, #82d02f 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #4aaf1b 0%, #82d02f 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #4aaf1b 0%, #82d02f 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #4aaf1b 0%, #82d02f 100%);
}
```

My slider, however, doesn't do that. I can only make it go to 100% - changing the width of the input will just make it go beyond the screen and making it very long horizontal.

How can I make so the maximum for the slider will fit into the div area that is getting filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/uHNsv/6/)

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    var max = $(this).attr("max");

    $(".slider-filled-top, .slider-filled-front").width(
        (this.value * 100 / max) + "%");
  });
});
```

Comment: This is much better than the answer you had before :P

Comment: Yeah I had a hard time understanding what he's looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

So there are two things going on here.

First you were putting `this.value + "%"` that is going to take whatever number you put in and turn it into a percentage.  So 2400 would be 2400%, that is huge.

```
$(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function(){
    $(".slider-filled-top, .slider-filled-front").width(this.value);
  });
});
```

Second if you want to set a new max value that is higher. you will also need to adjust your element to fit that amount.

html

```
<div id="slider">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="50">
  <div class="slider-filled-top"></div>
  <div class="slider-filled-front"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#slider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uHNsv/4/

Answer (score 0):

Modify CSS file, set `width:100%;` for `#slider` id
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/uHNsv/7/ for demo

Comment: Please just explain what you did and show the relevant CSS changes. Don't just copy the entire CSS.

Comment: set all #slider width to 100%.
for future use, simply include the slider div at another div with diferent width. Foer example : http://jsfiddle.net/edisutrisno/uHNsv/8/

Comment: Edit your answer and minify it